# Is there a way of sending an multipart/form-data array using python requests?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, multipartform-data

Assume there's an endpoint accepting `HTTP` requests with `multipart/form-data` content-type. Here's the example of the body of an acceptable request.

```
----------------------------033392576939750140334380
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file" filename="dummy_file.txt"
Some dummy file here.
----------------------------033392576939750140334380
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years"
2019
----------------------------033392576939750140334380
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years"
2020
----------------------------033392576939750140334380
```

As you can see, there's an array of numbers that are being sent using `years` keyword.

The questions is how can we send the same request using `requests` library in `python`?
It seems to be pretty tricky because of that `years` array.

I've tried to send it these ways.

```
requests.post(
        "http://some.site/some-endpoint/",
        files={
            "years": [2019, 2020],
            "file": ("dummy_file.txt", open("dummy_file.txt", "rb")),
        },
    )
```

Not going to work - `TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'list'`.

---

```
requests.post(
        "http://some.site/some-endpoint/",
        files={
            "years": (None, "2019, 2020"),
            "file": ("dummy_file.txt", open("dummy_file.txt", "rb")),
        },
    )
```

Gives the following request body.

```
--88c0aa2588fb3ca9b1e3c9c6cf625677
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years"
2019, 2020
--88c0aa2588fb3ca9b1e3c9c6cf625677
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dummy_file.txt"
Some dummy file here.
--88c0aa2588fb3ca9b1e3c9c6cf625677--
```

The `years` array is represented here as the string value which is not okay for this case.

---

```
requests.post(
        "http://some.site/some-endpoint/",
        files={
            "years[0]": (None, "2020"),
            "years[1]": (None, "2019"),
            "file": ("dummy_file.txt", open("dummy_file.txt", "rb")),
        },
    )
```

Gives the following request body.

```
--989f55fc01395402654f4275d11e8735
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years[0]"
2020
--989f55fc01395402654f4275d11e8735
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years[1]"
2019
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dummy_file.txt"
Some dummy file here.
--989f55fc01395402654f4275d11e8735
```

This way every element in the `years` array is represented by a different `name`, which is also not suitable for this particular case.

---

If we examine the last attempt it seems that we can achieve the required body structure by sending each value of `years` array using the same `years` keyword. But that's not going to work with `requests` as the `files` attribute accepts `dict` object which only allows unique keys.

So, how can we achieve this using `requests` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this in the docs: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests

Use a list of tuples to create the mapping, not a dict:

```py
r = requests.post(
    "https://httpbin.org/anything",
    files=[
        ("file", ("dummy_file.txt", b"File content....")),    
        ("years", (None, 2019)),
        ("years", (None, 2020)),
    ]
)
```

Data sent in `r.request.body`:

```
--8d763b42e4adf30aaefb9657df8bcf1b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="dummy_file.txt"

File content....
--8d763b42e4adf30aaefb9657df8bcf1b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years"

2019
--8d763b42e4adf30aaefb9657df8bcf1b
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="years"

2020
--8d763b42e4adf30aaefb9657df8bcf1b--
```

Comment: Thanks, this fully solves the problem. Weird that this moment is not included to the [API reference](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request).